# Hibernate LazyInitializationException with Lazy collection

Tags: hibernate

I'm actually experiencing a problem with Hibernate. I must say I'm a little new to this, but the code I have was already there and was built by people who know Hibernate. The problem is that I'm trying to migrate the Hibernate version from v3.2.5 to 3.6.9. The code actually in place works 100%, but when I changed the JAR and all the deprecated features, the same code doesn't work anymore. So, here is my problem:
I have a `Client` object, which has a many-to-many association with `Status` (we keep the history of the statuses). By default, this collection is LAZY. But, when I do a client research, I need this information, so I used the Criteria API. I then set the collection of statuses to EAGER, like this:

```
Criteria lStatuCriteria = lIntrvCriteria.createCriteria(SimIntrv.SIM_STATU_INTRVS, Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
```

And then I use the `Restrictions.in()` function in order to filter the statuses. Problem is, with 3.2.5, when the `list()` function of the Client object is called, the collection (set to lazy in the config file) is properly loaded. On the other hand, in 3.6.9, the collection is not loaded. I tryied setting the fetchmode using setFetchMode, but it didn't work.

Any Clue?

Comment: Show us more of your code. I think your code relied on a now fixed Hibernate bug to work properly. Using setFetchMode should work, but it all depends if you use it correctly or not. Without seeing the code, it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 0):

When you join to the statuses and filter on it hibernate expects that not all statuses will be returned by the query and does not initialize the collection. I guess in the old version the statuses are fetched with another roundtrip after the clients are loaded through a getter somewhere and it's not anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use lStatuCriteria.setFetchMode("mate", FetchMode.EAGER) to use Fetch mode as eager in criteria.

Comment: FetchMode.EAGER is a deprecated feature. FetchMode.JOIN. This is not an option since it implies lots of modifications